# Process exit code returning as 1 for applescript command and not opening terminal in macOS (happening for other ppl system)

Tags: java, macos, unix, terminal

below code is executed but not opening my mac os terminal on my colleague machine and returing exit code as 1 instead of 0

```
  Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
  String output= "";
  String[] myCommand = null;
  
  if(command.equals("open")) {
      String[] openTerminal = new String[] {
             //"/bin/bash", "-c", 
             "osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"" +
                    "echo Welcome to Tectonic" +"\"'"                   
        };

      myCommand = openTerminal;
  }

  try
  {
      Process p = runtime.exec(myCommand);
        InputStream stdIn = p.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdIn);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String line = null;

        
        int exitVal = p.waitFor();
        if(exitVal==0) {

        }
```

Comment: You're not processing stderr and you'll find `ProcessBuilder` makes that a lot easier. Also do'nt pile up long command strings. Use an array or list

Answer (score 0):

You'll see the error message if you add this after `exec`:

```
p.getErrorStream().transferTo(System.out);
```

Or merge stderr to stdout:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = pb.start();
process.getInputStream().transferTo(System.out);
int rc = process.waitFor();
```